# How do you find the size of an array within an array in C?

Tags: arrays, c

I'm working on a leetcode problem where you have to iterate through an array that contains other arrays of various lengths. I'm trying to find a way to get the length of the array within the array so that I can iterate through that array.. So far I've tried things like:

size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(int), size = sizeof(array) / sizeof(array[i]), etc..

But each time I get an integer value that seems unrelated to the array itself. I remember doing something like this before, but I can't remember how I did it.. Does anyone know the best way to accomplish something like this?

tl;dr:

Say we are given an **array = [[0,1,2],[0],[]]
How would I find the sizes of the individual arrays [0,1,2], [0], and [] within the given array of arrays? Thanks :)

Comment: @nicomp That makes sense, but even when I replace the i with a zero I’m still not getting the correct size.

Comment: You need to show the real code. `**array = [[0,1,2],[0],[]]` is not even close to being real code.

Comment: array[0] from your pseudo code would just be a pointer, a pointer has no concept of length

Comment: With a ragged array like `[[0,1,2],[0],[]]` there's no way of retrieving the sizes of each sub-array since that information doesn't exist at runtime. It's just a pointer to some memory of three addresses to some integers.

Comment: @AKX Thank you. I guess I have to go about solving the problem some other way then.

Comment: And regarding `sizeof` and "rather it's a preprocessor directive." isn't accurate either. it's an *operator*. Don't confuse preprocessor with compile-time with link-time with run-time. They're all very important, but distinct phases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make my comment an answer:

With a ragged array like `**array = [[0,1,2],[0],[]]` (pseudo-code, but we can infer what it means) there's no way of retrieving the sizes of each sub-array since that information doesn't exist at runtime. `**array` is just a pointer to some memory of three addresses to some integers.

The most minimal solution would be to have pointers to slightly "smarter" objects such as

```
struct IntArray {
  unsigned int count;
  int *data;
}
```

but that might not be possible for your Leetcode problem.